# PHP Mysqli update Where IN from serialize ajax post get variables in array

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am trying to update my SQL database but I get error `Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement`

I dont understand why I get this error. I use the folowing to sent data to my PHP

```
$.ajax({  
                     url:"UpdateMultipleAccounts.php",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data: $(".bootbox-body #myForm").serialize() +"&UpdatedID="+checkedid,
```

This gives the folowing payload response in network tab

```
TypeChecked: 0
AccType: 
CategoryChecked: 0
Category: 
RankerChecked: 0
Ranker: 
NotesChecked: 0
Notes: 
UpdatedID: 8548,8551,8544
```

And I use the folowing PHP code to make the update

print_r($_POST["UpdatedID"]);

```
$NotesResult = "NotesTest";
$in8  = str_repeat('?,', count($_POST["UpdatedID"]) - 1) . '?';
$types29 = str_repeat('i', count($_POST["UpdatedID"])); 
$sql8 = "UPDATE account SET notes = ? WHERE id IN (0,$in8) AND door = 'Martin' ";
$stmt8 = $mysqli->prepare($sql8);
$stmt8->bind_param('s' . $types29,$NotesResult, ... $_POST["UpdatedID"]);
$stmt8->execute();
$stmt8->close();
```

Thje response from the `print_r($_POST["UpdatedID"]);` in the response tab is

```
8548,8551,8544
```

So the variables are posted correctly, they are received correctly, why is my code telling me that there is nu data suplied? What am I doing wrong? Do I need to do something with the variable `$_POST["UpdatedID"]` before using it in the sql? I first need this to work before I can get the other post variables implented..

PS This worked when I did the ajax like this, so I am thinking it has something to do with the way the data is posted?

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "UpdateMultipleAccounts.php", data: {UpdatedID: checkedid},
```

Comment: I think you need to explode that string into an array

Comment: Any suggestions for this particulair case? I am a bit new to this. The post it self is allready like this 8548,8551,8544

Comment: `$data = explode(',', $_POST["UpdatedID"]);` and then use `$data`

Comment: Than easy, Thank you verry much ! Strange that this now is needed..

Comment: It isn’t really that strange. PHP won’t interpret strings for you. If those were three digits each, that’d be a normal number with digit separators.